# How to use Compass in Blackberry 7.0?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, compass-geolocation

I am showing a compass in my application. I have used the BlackBerry Developer guide ["Adding a compass field to an application"](http://docs.blackberry.com/ko-kr/developers/deliverables/34488/Adding_a_compass_overlay_to_an_app_1593376_11.jsp) to show a compass. Now I want to use the bearing to show direction in my compass -- that is, to show particular direction for the given latitude and longitude.

i want to show the arrow image in the direction of the particular location 
[image]

Comment: Please describe what you want a little more (maybe a picture)?  **How** do you want to show bearing?  Draw a line on top of your compass display?  Something else?  Please be specific.  Thanks.

Comment: when i open compass how to show direction to a particular location

Comment: I understand that.  I'm asking about how you want it to **look**?  What kind of visual indicator?

Comment: i have edited the question pls check this